# Illegal use of type as expression

Tags: c, compiler-errors, libharu

I have the following lines in my source code which is giving the error

> error C2275: 'HPDF_Array' : illegal use of this type as an expression"
>   :
>   This is the actual code in the header file:

```
 typedef struct _HPDF_Array_Rec  *HPDF_Array;

typedef struct _HPDF_Array_Rec {
    HPDF_Obj_Header  header;
    HPDF_MMgr        mmgr;
    HPDF_Error       error;
    HPDF_List        list;
} HPDF_Array_Rec;

    HPDF_Array id;
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Is `_HPDF_Array_Rec` defined? Is this your real code?

Comment: No this is actually part of an open source project called 'libharu'.

Comment: I don't think that this is actually the cause of your problem, but defining a symbol with the name `_HPDF_Array_Rec` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This code works on my compiler (gcc 4.7.1), so maybe you need to show more code or information in general if you're still having trouble:

```
// content of this struct is irrelevant, so I just made a dummy struct
struct _HPDF_Array_Rec {
    int dummy;
};


typedef struct _HPDF_Array_Rec  *HPDF_Array;
HPDF_Array id;
```

What the code in your question does, is define the type **HPDF_Array** as a pointer to the type **struct _HPDF_Array_Rec** and instantiate one **HPDF_Array** (which is a pointer to a _HDPF_Array_Rec struct) called id

---

**EDIT:**

The code still works fine. I googled the errorcode and got this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c9k4ah(v=vs.71).aspx

```
An expression uses the -> operator with a typedef identifier.
```

Check your code for that kind of error. Anywhere you're doing **HPDF_Array->something** instead of **id->something** ? :)

Comment: I just updated my question with more code, may be this will give more clarity. Is it ok to have to typedefs for a same struct - one defined and one not?

Answer (score 0):

If you have error while compiling `hpdf_pdfa.c` file, then move

```
HPDF_Array id;
```

line to the beginning of the `HPDF_PDFA_GenerateID(HPDF_Doc pdf)` function.

It appears that 2.2.1 branch was built as a C++ code, and the committer didn't notice the error. In the trunk branch this error is fixed.